# HTML tag place out of his container in code

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have
a php file like this in Wordpress (my theme)

```
<main>
<div></div>
...
<div></div>
</main>
```

in local (MAMP) all is fine

In line in the page result, a `<div>` go out of parent `<main>` and when I look at the page code on firefox, I see :

```
<main>
<div></div>
...
</main>
<div></div>
```

Do you experiment this behavior? Have you got some tips?

I have for exemple this page http://dev.orchestredepicardie.fr/concert/lorchestre-raconte/

This is source file. W3 validator said for exemple aside is not closed, but it is in the file.

I just find the error. Thank you for your coaching and tips. 
3 days without sleeping. I'm so happy !
It was an if condition bad coding and give /div without open tag div

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Fiche_concert
Template Post Type: concert
*/
?>
<?php
/**
 * theme wopi
 * fichier template php dédié à la page fiche du concert
 * 
 */

 get_header();
 get_template_part('header','concerts');

?>

<main>
    <div class="main_wrapper p_relative">
     <div class="back_container">
     <p><a href="javascript: window.history.go(-1);" class="back black">&#8672; RETOUR</a></p>
    </div>
  <div class="article_container flex_wrap">
   <article>
    <section class="presentation">
     <div class="presentation_wrapper">
      <div class="presentation_genre brique">
       <p><?php $concert_description_genre =  wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'genre', array("fields" => "names"));
          echo $concert_description_genre[0]; ?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="presentation_courte p_relative">
       <?php if(has_post_thumbnail() ){ ?>
       <div class="concert_img_wrapper">
        <div class="concert_img firstplan">
         <img class="p_relative" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="photo concert" title="Photo concert">
        </div>
       </div>
       <?php } ?>
       <div class="concert_titre_wrapper b_brique blanc">
        <div class="concert_titre">
         <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
    
    <?php if(empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_sstitre', true)) && empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_accroche', true)) ){} else {?>
    <section class="accroche b_brique">
     <div class="accroche_wrapper">
      <div class="accroche_sstitre blanc">
        <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_sstitre', true);?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="accroche_texte blanc">
        <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_accroche', true);?></p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
    <?php } ?>
    <section class="programme b_brique_o">
     <div class="programme_wrapper">
         <?php for ($i=1; $i<21; $i++) {?>
         <p>
          <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_prog_compositeur_'.$i, true))) 
           {
           echo '<span class="Programme_compositeur black">',get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_prog_compositeur_'.$i, true) , '</span>';} ?>
           <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_prog_oeuvre_'.$i, true))) 
           {
           echo '<span class="Programme_oeuvre blanc">', get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_prog_oeuvre_'.$i, true), '</span>';
           }} ?>
         </p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="distribution">
     <div class="distribution_wrapper flex_wrap">
<!-- Ensemble invité 1 -->
         <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_ensemble_invite_1', true))) {?>
         <div class="concert_distribution_item flex">
          <div class="distribution_photo b_brique">
           <?php 
           $distribution_photo = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_ensemble_invite_1', true),OBJECT,'collaboration');
           $distribution_lien = get_permalink($distribution_photo->ID);
           $distribution_photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($distribution_photo->ID);
           if(!empty($distribution_photo)) {?>
             <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><?php echo $distribution_photo; ?></a><?php } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="distribution_artiste">
           <?php $concert_distribution_poste = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_ensemble_invite_1', true),OBJECT,'collaboration');
             $concert_distribution_poste =  wp_get_post_terms($concert_distribution_poste->ID, 'coproduction', array("fields" => "names"));
             echo '<p class="concert_distribution_poste">', $concert_distribution_poste[0], "</p>"; ?>
             <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><p class="concert_distribution_nom"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_ensemble_invite_1', true);?></p></a>
          </div>
         </div><?php };?>
<!-- FIN Ensemble invité 1 -->
<!-- Ensemble invité 2 -->
         <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_ensemble_invite_2', true))) {?>
         <div class="concert_distribution_item flex">
          <div class="distribution_photo b_brique">
           <?php 
           $distribution_photo = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_ensemble_invite_2', true),OBJECT,'collaboration');
           $distribution_lien = get_permalink($distribution_photo->ID);
           $distribution_photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($distribution_photo->ID);
           if(!empty($distribution_photo)) {?>
            <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><?php echo $distribution_photo; ?></a><?php } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="distribution_artiste">
           <?php $concert_distribution_poste = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_ensemble_invite_2', true),OBJECT,'collaboration');
             $concert_distribution_poste =  wp_get_post_terms($concert_distribution_poste->ID, 'coproduction', array("fields" => "names"));
             echo '<p class="concert_distribution_poste">', $concert_distribution_poste[0], "</p>"; ?>
             <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><p class="concert_distribution_nom"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_ensemble_invite_2', true);?></p></a>
          </div>
         </div><?php };?>
<!-- FIN Ensemble invité 2 -->
<!-- Groupe ODP -->
         <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_distribution_ensemble_odp', true))) {?>
         
         <div class="concert_distribution_item flex">
          <div class="distribution_photo b_brique">
           <?php 
           $distribution_photo = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_distribution_ensemble_odp', true),OBJECT,'artiste');
           $distribution_lien = get_permalink($distribution_photo->ID);
           $distribution_photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($distribution_photo->ID);
           if(!empty($distribution_photo)) {?>
            <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><?php echo $distribution_photo; ?></a><?php } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="distribution_artiste">
           <?php $concert_distribution_poste = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_distribution_ensemble_odp', true),OBJECT,'artiste');
             $concert_distribution_poste =  wp_get_post_terms($concert_distribution_poste->ID, 'poste', array("fields" => "names"));
             echo '<p class="concert_distribution_poste">', $concert_distribution_poste[0], "</p>"; ?>
             <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><p class="concert_distribution_nom"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_distribution_ensemble_odp', true);?></p></a>
          </div>
         </div><?php };?>
<!-- FIN Groupe ODP -->         
<!-- ODP -->
         <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_distribution_odp', true)=="oui") {?>
         <div class="concert_distribution_item flex">
          <div class="distribution_photo b_brique">
           <img class="p_relative" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/images/orchestre_200.jpg)" alt="photo entete" title="L'Orchestre de Picardie photo">
          </div>
          <div class="distribution_artiste">
          <p class="concert_distribution_nom"><?php echo "Orchestre de Picardie";?></p>
          </div>
         </div><?php };?>
<!-- FIN ODP -->
<!-- Direction 1 -->
         <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_direction_1', true))) {?>
         <div class="concert_distribution_item flex">
          <div class="distribution_photo b_brique">
           <?php 
           $distribution_photo = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_direction_1', true),OBJECT,array('collaboration','artiste'));
           $distribution_lien = get_permalink($distribution_photo->ID);
           $distribution_photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($distribution_photo->ID);
           if(!empty($distribution_photo)) {?>
            <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><?php echo $distribution_photo; ?></a><?php } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="distribution_artiste">
           <?php $concert_distribution_poste = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_direction_1', true),OBJECT,array('collaboration','artiste'));
             $concert_distribution_poste =  wp_get_post_terms($concert_distribution_poste->ID, 'poste', array("fields" => "names"));
             echo '<p class="concert_distribution_poste">', $concert_distribution_poste[0], "</p>"; ?>
             <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><p class="concert_distribution_nom"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_direction_1', true);?></p></a>
          </div>
         </div><?php };?>
<!-- FIN Direction 1 -->
<!-- Direction 2 -->
         <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_direction_2', true))) {?>
         <div class="concert_distribution_item flex">
          <div class="distribution_photo b_brique">
           <?php 
           $distribution_photo = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_direction_2', true),OBJECT,array('collaboration','artiste'));
           $distribution_lien = get_permalink($distribution_photo->ID);
           $distribution_photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($distribution_photo->ID);
           if(!empty($distribution_photo)) {?>
            <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><?php echo $distribution_photo; ?></a><?php } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="distribution_artiste">
           <?php $concert_distribution_poste = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_direction_2', true),OBJECT,array('collaboration','artiste'));
             $concert_distribution_poste =  wp_get_post_terms($concert_distribution_poste->ID, 'poste', array("fields" => "names"));
             echo '<p class="concert_distribution_poste">', $concert_distribution_poste[0], "</p>"; ?>
             <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><p class="concert_distribution_nom"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_direction_2', true);?></p></a>
          </div>
         </div><?php };?>
<!-- FIN Direction 2 -->
<!-- Artistes Invité 1 à 10 -->
         <?php   for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++) {?>
         <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_artiste_inv_'.$i, true))) {?>
         <div class="concert_distribution_item flex">
          <div class="distribution_photo b_brique">
           <?php 
           $distribution_photo = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_artiste_inv_'.$i, true),OBJECT,'collaboration');
           $distribution_lien = get_permalink($distribution_photo->ID);
           $distribution_photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($distribution_photo->ID);
           if(!empty($distribution_photo)) {?>
            <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><?php echo $distribution_photo; ?></a><?php } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="distribution_artiste">
           <?php $concert_distribution_poste = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_artiste_inv_'.$i, true),OBJECT,'collaboration');
             $concert_distribution_poste =  wp_get_post_terms($concert_distribution_poste->ID, 'poste', array("fields" => "names"));
             echo '<p class="concert_distribution_poste">', $concert_distribution_poste[0], "</p>"; ?>
             <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><p class="concert_distribution_nom"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_artiste_inv_'.$i, true);?></p></a>
          </div>
         </div><?php };?><?php }?>
<!-- FIN Artistes Invité 1 à 10 -->
<!-- Artistes 1 à 10 -->
         <?php   for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++) {?>
         <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_artiste_'.$i, true))) {?>
         <div class="concert_distribution_item flex">
          <div class="distribution_photo b_brique">
           <?php 
           $distribution_photo = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_artiste_'.$i, true),OBJECT,'artiste');
           $distribution_lien = get_permalink($distribution_photo->ID);
           $distribution_photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($distribution_photo->ID);
           if(!empty($distribution_photo)) {?>
            <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><?php echo $distribution_photo; ?></a><?php } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="distribution_artiste">
           <?php $concert_distribution_poste = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_artiste_'.$i, true),OBJECT,'artiste');
             $concert_distribution_poste =  wp_get_post_terms($concert_distribution_poste->ID, 'poste', array("fields" => "names"));
             echo '<p class="concert_distribution_poste">', $concert_distribution_poste[0], "</p>"; ?>
             <a href="<?php echo $distribution_lien; ?>"><p class="concert_distribution_nom"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_artiste_'.$i, true);?></p></a>
          </div>
         </div><?php };?><?php }?>
<!-- FIN Artistes 1 à 10 -->


     </div>
    </section>





   </article>






   <aside>

    <section class="aside_top b_brique p_relative">
     <div class="aside_top_wrapper">
      <div class="duree blanc">
       <div class="duree_wrapper">
        <p><span class="duree_titre">Durée </span><span class="duree_texte"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_duree', true); ?></span></p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
    
    <div class="choix"><p>&#8675; Cliquer sur la salle</p></div>
    <section class="dates b_brique">
     <div class="dates_wrapper">
        <?php for ($i=1; $i<10; $i++) {
        $event_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_date_'.$i, true);

       if(!empty($event_date)){?>
      <section class="date_item">
        <div class="date_jour">
         <p>
         <?php 
           echo '<span class="concert_pratique_date blanc">', mysql2date('l j F Y', get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_date_'.$i, true)), '</span>';
           echo '<span class="concert_pratique_heure">', get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_horaire_'.$i, true), '</span>'; ?>
         </p>

        </div>

        <?php
        if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_lieu_'.$i, true))){ 
        ?> 

        <div class="date_ville">
         <div>
            <?php
            $concert_pratique_ville = get_page_by_path(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_lieu_'.$i, true),OBJECT,'lieu');
            $concert_pratique_ville =  wp_get_post_terms($concert_pratique_ville->ID, 'lieu', array("fields" => "names"));
            if(!empty($concert_pratique_ville[0])){?>

            <div class="concert_pratique_ville line"><p><?php echo $concert_pratique_ville[0]; ?></p></div>
            <div class="concert_pratique_salle line">
             <p><?php echo get_page_by_path(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_lieu_'.$i, true),OBJECT,'lieu')->post_title; ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
         </div>
        </div>
            <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_lieu_'.$i, true))){ ?>
    <div  id="salle_info_pratique_item_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="salle_info_pratique">
     <div class="salle_info_pratique_wrapper ">

      <div class="salle_info_pratique_item">
       <div class="salle_info_pratique_item_wrapper">

        <div class="salle_lieu">

        <?php
          echo '<p class="salle_lieu_salle">',get_page_by_path(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_lieu_'.$i, true),OBJECT,'lieu')->post_title, '</p>';
          if(!empty($concert_pratique_ville[0])){
           echo '<p class="salle_lieu_ville">', $concert_pratique_ville[0], '</p>';}

          ?>
        </div>


        <?php 
         $salle_post = get_page_by_path(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_lieu_'.$i, true),OBJECT,'lieu');
         $salle_url = get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_concert_billeterie', true);
         if(!empty($salle_url)) {?>
        <div class="salle_reserver">
          <p><a href="<?php echo $salle_url; ?>" target="_blank">Réserver</a></p><?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div class="salle_photo">
          <?php 
          $salle_photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($salle_post->ID);
          if(!empty($salle_photo)) {?>
           <?php echo $salle_photo; ?><?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="salle_adresse">
         <?php 
          $salle_adresse = get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_salle_adresse', true);
          if(!empty($salle_adresse)) {?>
           <p class="salle_adresse_texte"><?php echo $salle_adresse; ?></p><?php } ?>
         <?php 
          $salle_phone = get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_salle_phone', true);
          if(!empty($salle_phone)) {?>
           <p class="salle_phone_texte"><?php echo $salle_phone; ?></p><?php } ?>
         <?php 
          $salle_mail = get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_salle_mail', true);
          if(!empty($salle_mail)) {?>
           <p class="salle_mail_texte line"><a href="mailto:<?php echo $salle_mail; ?>">Envoyer un mail</a></p><?php } ?>
         <?php 
          $salle_url = get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_salle_url', true);
          if(!empty($salle_url)) {?>
           <p class="salle_url_texte line"><a href="<?php echo $salle_url; ?>" target="_blank">Site internet</a></p><?php } ?>

        </div>

        <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_concert_tarif_1', true))) { ?>
        <div class="salle_Tarif">
         <p class="salle_Tarif_titre">Tarifs</p>
         <?php   
          $salle_tarif_1 = get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_concert_tarif_1', true);
          $salle_tarif_2 = get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_concert_tarif_2', true);
          $salle_tarif_3 = get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_concert_tarif_3', true);
          $salle_tarif_4 = get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_concert_tarif_4', true);
          $salle_tarif_5 = get_post_meta($salle_post->ID, '_concert_tarif_5', true);
          if(!empty($salle_tarif_1)) {?><p><?php echo $salle_tarif_1; ?></p><?php };
          if(!empty($salle_tarif_2)) {?><p><?php echo $salle_tarif_2; ?></p><?php };
          if(!empty($salle_tarif_3)) {?><p><?php echo $salle_tarif_3; ?></p><?php };
          if(!empty($salle_tarif_4)) {?><p><?php echo $salle_tarif_4; ?></p><?php };
          if(!empty($salle_tarif_5)) {?><p><?php echo $salle_tarif_5; ?></p><?php };
          ?>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <div class="salle_description">
         <?php 
          $salle_description = get_post_field('post_content', $salle_post->ID);
          if(!empty($salle_description)) {?>
           <p>
            <?php 
            $salle_description = apply_filters('the_content', $salle_description);
            $salle_description = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $salle_description);
            echo $salle_description; ?>
           </p>
           <?php } ?>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>





     </div>


    </div>
    <?php } ?>

      </section> 
      <?php }}} ?>

     </div>
    </section>



   </aside>
   

   
        </div>
   <div class="" >
    <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_video', true))){?>
    <section class="video">
     <div class="video_wrapper black">
      <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="400" height="253.125"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_video', true); ?>"
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>
    </section>
    <?php } ?>
    <section class="description">
     <div class="description_wrapper black">
      <?php while(have_posts())  : the_post(); ?>
      <?php the_content(); ?>          
      <?php endwhile; ?>
     </div>
    </section>
   </div> 
  <section class="partenaire">
   <div class="partenaire_wrapper black">
    <div class="partenaire_titre"><p>Avec le soutien de</p></div>
    <div class="partenaire_liste flex_wrap">
       
       <?php 
       for ($i=1; $i<16; $i++) {
       if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_partenaire_logo_'.$i, true))) {?>
       <div class="partenaire_item">
        <div class="partenaire_photo">
         <?php 
         $partenaire_photo = get_page_by_title(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_concert_partenaire_logo_'.$i, true),OBJECT,'administration');
         $partenaire_photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($partenaire_photo->ID);
         if(!empty($partenaire_photo)) {?>
          <?php echo $partenaire_photo; ?><?php } ?>
        </div>
       </div><?php }};?>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>
    </div>
</main>

<?php
 get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: Really need more info. Can you provide a sample of your .php code?

Comment: You may possibly be missing a close tag on one of your tags. That could be messing with it. In addition, although highly unlikely, if at some point that `<div>` was outside the `<main>` tag at some point, it might be saved in the cache.

Comment: Within WP I find it best to use the semantic tags to wrap php calls.
<main>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</main>

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ is a good online HTML validator. Different browsers can show invalid HTML in different ways.

Comment: I have for exemple this page http://dev.orchestredepicardie.fr/concert/lorchestre-raconte/

Comment: I ran your page through validator.w3.org. It shows multiple div and section tags that are not properly closed. Please try it. validator.w3.org is very easy to use. Finding the mismatch is best done with an HTML editor.

Comment: Hello, I saw the tags unclosed in validatorW3. But there are tags not closed on result page. In my php file this tags are well closed. I put source file in my question.

Comment: The php code is used to generate HTML. The only thing that matters is the HTML that is generated.

Comment: If the template works with a different post then it is the data in the post that is the critical difference. Your template has many if conditions. All these conditions may not be the same for both posts. Another possibility is that the data itself contains bad HTML. Anyway, I would really believe validator.w3.org.

Comment: I don't find which post datas could cause this. I'm serching without success ;(

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of html markup errors, such as unclosed `<div>`'s and `<section>`'s, and those will cause display errors and content flowing out of containers and sidebars out of place. Use the W3C Validator https://validator.w3.org/ to check your code.

See [Showing results for http://dev.orchestredepicardie.fr/concert/lorchestre-raconte/](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.orchestredepicardie.fr%2Fconcert%2Florchestre-raconte%2F) for errors and line numbers. The html yoiu need to fix will be in different theme files, such as header.php, page.php, etc; you'll need to check your theme.

You can ignore the warnings about "The type attribute is unnecessary for JavaScript resources" and the missing headings, but fix the unclosed divs's and other clear errors.

Comment: Thank you. i notice that the tags are not closed on published page. But on source file, there are closed. In some other post there are not these error

Comment: For exemple the same template in another wordpress post is ok w3 validator. http://dev.orchestredepicardie.fr/concert/opera-pour-enfants/

Comment: Must be code from the post editor that is causing the issues.

Comment: I don't know what it could make this behavior in post content. There is no tag on the_content except em or strong. And there are some custom field.

Comment: I just find the error. Thank you for your coaching and tips. 3 days without sleeping. I'm so happy ! It was an if condition bad coding and give /div without open tag div